# Facebook IOS SDK 3.14 - Inconsistent results in Graph API friends birthdays queries

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

We recently updated the SDK to v3.14.By default, were requesting the users for the following permissions: @"user_birthday",@"user_friends",@"public_profile",@"email",@"friends_birthday"
and use the query @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,birthday,name,picture&access_token=.."

We've noticed that birthday information is missing for some of users. The behavior is inconsistent.

For example:for one of our users, only 30 out 600 friends are returned in the JSON request.. I believe it not reasonable all the others revoked their permissions..
In another case, all friends were returned, but most returned without the birthday field - see two entries from the same response:

no birthday:
{"id":"616933360","name":"XXX XXXX","picture":{"data":{"url":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/t1.0-1/c40.0.100.100/s50x50/1098171_10151793243593361_626621565_a.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}}

with birthday:
{"id":"590531323","birthday":"05/31/1983","name":"XXX XXX","picture":{"data":{"url":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/t1.0-1/c0.8.50.50/p50x50/1660299_10151840501221324_512792944_t.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}}

I've tried the Graph Api Explorer tool and saw similar results. The token debugger also shows that the token is valid.

Does anyone else experience this behavior? Is this a bug in facebook API?

Comment: "only 30 out 600 friends are returned" - smells like pagination. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476795/handle-pagination-of-facebook-user-photos) - it's about handling pagination of user photos. Perhaps it will push you in right direction.

Comment: Are you using API v1.0 or v2.0?

Comment: v2.0, but i tried v1.0 with the graph api explorer-same results.

Comment: doesn't seem to be paging as well. I've tried limiting my calls to 25 results. I'm receiving 25 on the first time, 4 the second time and none on the third..